LiveCharts 2 and different color items in series points

How do I modify the series points to get say one point green or red. Also there is a bar chart. How could I do the same? Can I turn one bar red based on some value or threshold?
That would be really great. Also I am using version2 and that has different assemblies to version 1 and I think it is much better but they are different.
Thanks!!!
Have not tried anything yet. Not sure where to start of that. you need a series an xaxis and a yaxis on these series
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Painting;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;

